# How can I test submatrices of a matrix to see if they contain all zeroes?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've a large matrix, say `A[1,10,10000]`, which contains 10000 1-by-10 submatrices. I want to check each of these submatrices to find which ones contain all zeroes. How can I do this?

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to check if `A` has all zeroes, or if a submatrix in `A` has all zeroes?

Comment: sub matrices. I want to check each and every individual matrices independently.

Comment: I edited the question. There are 10000 1-by-10 matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using the functions [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) and [SQUEEZE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html):

```
allZeroIndex = squeeze(all(all(A == 0,2),1));
```

And this will give you a [logical](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-97022.html) vector `allZeroIndex` that has the same length as the third dimension of `A` and contains a 1 (i.e. true) for matrices that have all zeroes and 0 (i.e. false) for matrices that contain non-zero values.

**NOTE:** Of course the above would really only be appropriate for a matrix of integer values. If there is the chance that you will have floating point values in `A`, then odds are good that you may never get *exactly* 0 for a value. In such a case, you need to check for values that are within some threshold of 0, like so:

```
allNearZeroIndex = squeeze(all(all(abs(A) < 1e-10,2),1));
```

Comment: can I use this: find(all(all( sum(matrixX,2) == 0 ))) ?

Comment: No.  Your method will be fooled by rows which sum to zero, even if they do not contain all zeros.

Comment: >>A = ones(1,4,9999);
>> allZero = all(A(:) == 0)

allZero =

     0

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to use nnz.

```
if nnz(A) == 0
  disp('Yup, this is one really boring matrix.')
end
```

Comment: The question title is misleading. The OP actually wants to test *submatrices* of a matrix for zeroes, not the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `all`, you can also use `sum`:

```
allZero = sum(sum(A==0)); % will be non-zero if there are non-zero values
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using nnz is probably the best bet, but didn't know about that until now.  Instead I would have used unique():  if unique(A)==0 ...